# Click close button on a div with triggering div click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a close button in a DIV, with both the DIV and the close button also having `click()` events attached to them. When I click the close button it also triggers the div `click()` event. I know I could put a SPAN inside the div and attach my click event to the span instead of the DIV, but is there a way I can keep both the div click event and the close button click event and not trigger the div `click()` when I click the close button?

```
<div id="sendFeedback" class="feedback with-round-borders with-padding with-box-shadows">Send us your feedback <span id="closeFeedback" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" style="float:right"></span></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#sendFeedback").click(function() {
   alert('test');
 });
$("#closeFeedback").click(function() {
 $("#sendFeedback").fadeOut();
})
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5VPN/1/

Comment: It sounds like the click even is bubbling unexpectedly. if you use jquery's $(selector).bind() method to attach the event, you can stop bubbling by declaring a value of false for the function's third argument. (i.e: $(selector).bind('click', function(){}, false).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `event.stopPropagation()` to the `<span>` click event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendFeedback").click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
    $("#closeFeedback").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#sendFeedback").fadeOut();
    })
});
```

`.stopPropagation()` will stop the event from bubbling up to the div (or any other ancestor): http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Here is your jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/t5VPN/2/

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Jasper. 9 minutes to accepted answer.

Comment: for future reference to any searchers: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 2):

Yep. You should cancel the bubbling of the event up in the DOM tree.

For futher info see the [Event#stopPropagation()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation) in the DOM Event documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#closeFeedback').click(function(e){
     $('#sendFeedback').fadeOut();
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```